# How to link the values for a linked list automatically using python

Tags: python, data-structures

I've started learning data structures using python. I've been stuck with this since yesterday and haven't thought of a solution yet. The tutorials I see on the internet links the values of a linked list manually. I've been searching and thinking if there is a way to do it automatically.
Here is a sample code from tutorialspoint.com

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, dataval=None):
        self.dataval = dataval
        self.nextval = None

class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headval = None

    def listprint(self):
        printval = self.headval
        while printval is not None:
            print (printval.dataval)
            printval = printval.nextval

list = SLinkedList()
list.headval = Node("Mon")
e2 = Node("Tue")
e3 = Node("Wed")

# Link first Node to second node
list.headval.nextval = e2

# Link second Node to third node
e2.nextval = e3

list.listprint()
```

Comment: You can. But  you have to pass the constructor a node for it to be linked *to* something. Currently a node only receives its own data (dataval) so it doesn't know  anything but that.

Answer (score 0):

like @Reut Sharabani said in the comment right now the node constructor takes only the dataval and set the next one to be None. To get the behavior you want you would have to make a second constructor where you give dataval and next to the Node. In your SLinkedList class you will then construct the linked list in reverse by starting at the tail node and moving to towards the head. 
If this what you meant by automatic.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here's one way you might do it, without disrupting the current set-up of
your classes too much:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = None

    @classmethod
    def from_iterable(cls, iterable):
        node = cls()
        iterable = iter(iterable)
        try:
            node.data = next(iterable)
        except StopIteration:
            return None
        node.next_node = cls.from_iterable(iterable)
        return node

class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self, head_node=None):
        self.head_node = head_node

    @classmethod
    def from_iterable(cls, iterable):
        return cls(Node.from_iterable(iterable))

    def listprint(self):
        print_node = self.head_node
        while print_node is not None:
            print(print_node.data)
            print_node = print_node.next_node

my_list = SLinkedList.from_iterable(["Mon", "Tue", "Wed"])
my_list.listprint()
```

with output

```
Mon
Tue
Wed
```

I've renamed a couple of bits here (remember `list` is a Python builtin!) and
there and changed some function signatures to be a little more natural, but
mostly what I've just done is added the two `from_iterable` methods.

This is a very recursive implementation. If you need lists bigger than about
1000 elements you'll have to write it all in terms of while loops (although a
linked list implementation like this in pure Python won't ever be very fast)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to add an element into a linked list. You can insert an element either in first position (trivial) or after an existing node (slightly more complex because you have to specify how to designate that node).

```
...
class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.headval = None

    def listprint(self):
        printval = self.headval
        while printval is not None:
            print (printval.dataval)
            printval = printval.nextval

    def insertfirst(self, val):
        node = Node(val)
        node.nextval = self.headval
        self.headval = node

>>> lst = SLinkedList()     # do not use list which is the standard library list
>>> lst.insertfirst("Wed")
>>> lst.insertfirst("Tue")
>>> lst.insertfirst("Mon")
>>> lst.listprint()
Mon
Tue
Wed
```